# Collect and order the DataFrame column

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, dataset

I have a DataFrame as below

```
A B C
1 3 1
1 8 2
1 5 3
2 2 1
```

My output should be, Column B is ordered based on the initial column B value

```
A B
1 3,1/5,3/8,2
2 2,1
```

I wrote something like this is scala

```
df.groupBy("A").withColumn("B",collect_list(concat("B",lit(","),"C"))
```

But dint solves my problem.

Comment: could you please edit your question to display the correct format of your data and code. this can be done by highlighting it and pressing Ctrl+K

Comment: how are you deriving the B column? - its not clear

Comment: Its group by column A

Comment: yeah, then where does `1/5` come from?

Comment: / is a separator

Comment: how do you expect there to be multiple separators in a list?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have input dataframe as

```
+---+---+---+
|A  |B  |C  |
+---+---+---+
|1  |3  |1  |
|1  |8  |2  |
|1  |5  |3  |
|2  |2  |1  |
+---+---+---+
```

You can get following output as

```
+---+---------------+
|A  |B              |
+---+---------------+
|1  |[3,1, 5,3, 8,2]|
|2  |[2,1]          |
+---+---------------+
```

By doing simple `groupBy`, `aggregations` and using [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#concat_ws(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.spark.sql.Column...))

```
df.orderBy("B").groupBy("A").agg(collect_list(concat_ws(",", col("B"), col("C"))) as "B")
```

You can use `udf` function to get the final desired result as

```
def joinString = udf((b: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => {
  b.mkString("/")
} )

newdf.withColumn("B", joinString(col("B"))).show(false)
```

You should get

```
+---+-----------+
|A  |B          |
+---+-----------+
|1  |3,1/5,3/8,2|
|2  |2,1        |
+---+-----------+
```

**Note** you would need `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` for all of the above to work

**Edited**

> > Column B is ordered based on the initial column B value

For this you can just remove the orderBy part as

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val newdf = df.groupBy("A").agg(collect_list(concat_ws(",", col("B"), col("C"))) as "B")

def joinString = udf((b: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => {
  b.mkString("/")
} )

newdf.withColumn("B", joinString(col("B"))).show(false)
```

and you should get output as

```
+---+-----------+
|A  |B          |
+---+-----------+
|1  |3,1/8,2/5,3|
|2  |2,1        |
+---+-----------+
```

Comment: But this wont give me an order

Comment: It throws an error saying, withcolumn is not a member of relationalgroupeddataset

Comment: Thank you. Its works fine. But, the problem is with large data. The order is not maintained when handling this with large data. May be because of group by dont maintain the order?

Comment: nope, groupBy doesn't maintain order. You will have to use orderBy as I used but that won't give you the same order as the original. If the answer helps you can accept the answer :) thanks

Comment: @Deek i have updated answer I hope I got it correct this time

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can achieve by using concat_ws function and then groupby column A and collect the list

```
val df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ( 1, 3, 1),
  (1, 8, 2),
  (1, 5, 3),
  (2, 2, 1)
)).toDF("A", "B", "C")

val result = df1.withColumn("B", concat_ws("/", $"B", $"C"))

result.groupBy("A").agg(collect_list($"B").alias("B")).show
```

Output:

```
+---+---------------+
|  A|              B|
+---+---------------+
|  1|[3/1, 8/2, 5/3]|
|  2|          [2/1]|
+---+---------------+
```

**Edited:**
Here is what you can do if you want to sort with the column B

```
val format = udf((value : Seq[String]) => {
  value.sortBy(x => {x.split(",")(0)}).mkString("/")
})


val result = df1.withColumn("B", concat_ws(",", $"B", $"C"))
  .groupBy($"A").agg(collect_list($"B").alias("B"))
  .withColumn("B", format($"B"))

result.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----------+
|  A|          B|
+---+-----------+
|  1|3,1/5,3/8,2|
|  2|        2,1|
+---+-----------+
```

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: My output should be basically, [3,1 / 8,2 / 5,3]

Comment: You can get the order after group by if you want you need to sort it later as you want. Above is the code updated hope this helps